# Is it proper to re-use id's in a multi-page template?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In one of Salesforce's jQuery Mobile examples, [this page](https://github.com/developerforce/MobilePack-jQueryMobile/blob/master/Samples/jQueryMobileHerokuNode/public/not-index.html) in the app re-uses the id FirstName, LastName and Email.

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="detailpage">
    <div data-role="header">
    <a href='#mainpage' id="back" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
       <h1>Contact Detail</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <table>
            <tr><td>First Name:</td><td id="FirstName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td id="LastName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td id="Email"></td></tr>
        </table>
        <form name="detail" id="detail">
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" />
            <button data-role="button" id="editbtn">Edit</button>
            <button data-role="button" id="deletebtn" data-icon="delete" 
              data-theme="e">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Force.com</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="editpage">
    <div data-role="header">
    <a href='#mainpage' id="back" class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
        <h1 id="formheader">New Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form name="contact" id="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="Id" />
            <table>
                <tr><td>First Name:</td><td ><input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" 
                  data-theme="c"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td ><input name="LastName" id="LastName" 
                      data-theme="c"/></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td><input name="Email" id="Email" 
                      data-theme="c"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button data-role="button" id="actionbtn">Action</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I know that it is invalid HTML to use the same id multiple times.  This is one HTML document, yet within the multi-page template each `<div data-role="page">` is technically a separate page.

So my question is: is this a proper approach? And if not, what is the most elegant way to avoid reusing id's without redundant code? In this case, I assume it is convenient to have the same id to be able to select the table elements depending on which page you are on without specifying separate event handlers for each page (but maybe it is just a copy and paste mistake).

**EDIT**: I realize that using classes is the clear solution, so I guess part of the question is: how to select, for example, only the class Firstname in the current div/page?  Perhaps the question- "is this valid HTML?" may seem obvious, the reason I asked the question is I thought perhaps I was missing something if it was in Salesforce's example.

**EDIT 2**: I just found this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-ids-in-jquery-mobile-pages for a good discussion on the issue.

Comment: It is not valid, however, you can work with them by always using selectors that would end up being passed to queryselectorall, such as `#thepageid #theinputid`. Obviously that's less efficient, and this being a mobile environment, efficiency is very important so i'd suggest finding another way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all forger what ever you learned about valid **`HTML`** when working with jQuery Mobile. You need to remember that on a basic level jQuery Mobile works a little bit different then normal web development. If multi-page template is used **`DOM`** can/will hold more then one page. There's really no point in forcing unique id's.

jQuery Mobile has only one real rule when working with id's and it is that pages **`MUST`** have unique id's (plus they can't start with number or be only a number), everything else can have duplicate id's, in some cases it is a prerequisite. For example, when you want to override a classic jQuery Mobile button styles (or any other widget) you would want to use same id's on every custom button. If you use id for a custom button you will not need to use **`!important`** to override classic **`CSS`** styles.

Regarding your last question. It is possible to access only id's found on a current active page. It can be done easily with this jQuery Mobile selector:

```
$.mobile.activePage
```

for example, this code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    alert($.mobile.activePage.attr('id'));
});​
```

will give you an id of a currently active page. Basically it is a selector of a currant active page div. For example you can use function **`find`** to access inner page content.

But there's a catch, it can be used only during pagebeforeshow, pageshow, pagebeforehide and pagehide page events. Unfortunately I don't know how much do you understand jQuery Mobile, in case you don't know what page events are then take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

Comment: Thanks, this is the jQuery Mobile specific answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It is not valid HTML.  [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org) gives the error "Duplicate ID FirstName" and also gives a similar for the others.  That said, most modern browsers will try to do something reasonable when given invalid HTML.

Comment: Didn't know about validator.w3.org. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it is not valid, and the most elegant solution is to use the class attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute of all your elements must be not only unique on a given page, but also unique across the pages in a site. This is because jQuery Mobile's single-page navigation model allows many different "pages" to be present in the DOM at the same time. This also applies when using a multi-page template, since all "pages" on the template are loaded at once.

Ref: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/pages/